# JSF <trh:script>rendering and running order

Tags: java, html, jsf, cross-browser, trinidad

what is the order the javascipt function is running. each browser do something else
for example I have this code:

```html
  <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{messages.signInMessage}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputLabel for="username" value="#{messages.usernameLabel}" />
 </h:panelGrid>
 <trh:script>
       // do some logic
       // alert("end!");
 </trh:script>
```

I want that the script will run always after the panel is fully rendered so I could take his width for example and do with this something the the javascript function.

this works fine with in all browsers except for IE 8 
the script is running before the panel was fully rendered.

any one can help me understand this issue , what is the correct order 
in more genreal what are the difference between the browsers : IE,Chrome,FF etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<tr:document>
  <trh:script source="jquery.js"></trh:script>
  <trh:script source="your_script.js"></trh:script>
  ...
</tr:document>
```

You can then just execute your script on page load ([`.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Your stuff here
});
```

If you are using Ajax ([Trinidad Partial Page Rendering](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/ppr.html)), you might want to add a [state change listener](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/ppr.html#Javascript_APIs_for_PPR) in your Javascript. For example:

```
TrPage.getInstance().getRequestQueue().addStateChangeListener(function(state){
  if (state == TrRequestQueue.STATE_READY){
    // Your stuff here
  }
});
```